# Aparecer o valor total

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um sistema para uma loja virtual, do qual o usuário terá o valor do pacote. Por ex.: R$ 12.000,00, porém ele terá a opção de escolher o seguro viagem através do código abaixo:

```
Seguro Viagem?<br>
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' value='Sim'> Sim
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' value='Não'> Não
```

Tem como ao selecionar Sim, o valor do seguro viagem ser somado com o valor do pacote e alterar o valor final? Ex.:

( sem seguro )
Valor: R$ 12.000,00

Ao clicar em Sim, alterar para:

( com seguro )
Seguro: R$ 500,00
Valor: R$ 12.500,00

Tentei usar o código abaixo, mas não está funcionando:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function soma(){
valorSeguro = 500.00;
valorPacote = 1200.00;
e = valorSeguro + valorPacote; 
if(e.toFixed(2) == "NaN"){
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "USD 0.00";
}else{
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "USD "+e.toFixed(2)+"";
}
}
</script>
Seguro Viagem?<br>
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' onchange="soma()" value='Sim'> Sim
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' value='Não'> Não<br><br>

<div id="total" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:16px">USD 12.000,00</div>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Vamos apagar os comentarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vi que você já resolveu o problema. Mas vou deixar a resposta como alternativa.

```js
var valorSeguro = 500.00;
var valorPacote = 1200.00;

$('input:radio[name="Seguro"]').change( function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Sim') {
    var valorTotal = valorSeguro + valorPacote;
    $("#total").html("Valor total: USD " + valorTotal);
  } else {
    $("#total").html("Valor total: USD " + valorPacote);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Seguro Viagem?<br>
<input id="comSeguro" type='radio' name='Seguro' value='Sim'> Sim
<input type='radio' name='Seguro' value='Não'> Não

<p id="total">Valor total:</p>
```